# how to change the default path of mysql (into outfile) csv path

Tags: mysql

i have installed WAMP and using mysql, however using sql query (into outfile) and storing the csv file on default location under wamp folder/bin/mysql/data folder.

I want to override this location and want to store the csv file on any location.

Please let me know how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT a,b,a+b INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM test_table;

Comment: Hello Ankit, please let me know how to do it on windows, i tried giving the absoulte path ex : c://. still it is storing under wamp folder

Answer (score 0):

In window environment

```
select * into outfile 'c:/resources.txt' fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"' lines
terminated by '\n' from resources;
```